# EditText с проверкой и заменой editable.replace, проблема при очистки поля

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

(Android, Коtlin) Помогите люди умные, пытаюсь в EditText (тип ввода numberDecimal) на лету проверять вводимые данные используя textWatcher. Мне нужно при вводе вполе 0745 получить 0.745
Это срабатывает, но после ввода, в поле не получается полностью очистить поле, так как начинает работать условие и подставлять ноль с точкой. (0.) остается в поле.

[image: очистить поле]

```
blok1.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher())

private fun textWatcher(): TextWatcher {
    return object :
        TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) {
            try {
                val none = Integer.parseInt(editable.toString())
                if (none == 0) {
                    editable.replace(0, editable.length, "0.")
                }
            } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) {
    // добавляет точку, если первый введённый символ 0, а следующий не является точкой
    if (editable.length > 1 && editable[0] == '0' && editable[1] != '.') {
        editable.insert(1, ".")
    }
}
```